# Batch file: pass a block of commands instead of a script.tcl

Tags: batch-file, tcl

I run a .tcl script using a .bat file as per the simplified example below:

script.tcl

```
set a "this is the script"
puts $a
```

script.bat

```
echo off
set tclpath="C:\tclsh.exe"
set filepath="C:\script.tcl"
%tclpath% %filepath%
```

I wonder whether I can include in the .bat file the commands of the .tcl script, so instead of having two files I just have one .bat file that runs tclsh.exe and passes the commands to the tcl shell.

Is this possible? and how can I do it?

Comment: I think you'll have to read the `tclsh` manual for that. That's not batch related

Comment: Since I code in tcl I have set the .tcl extension to be opened by Notepad++ or any other similar text editor. I also use, as a personal shortcut, to define the extension .tclmine associated to tclsh.exe, in that way I just doubleclick on it and it executes the code I want. But this approach lacks of portability to other machines, while .bat file are supported by any MS Windows PC. That's why I asked whether it was possible to pass commands from a .bat file to the tcl shell.

Comment: You probably can.  We have a running thread over on Dostips that shows how to run different scripting languages with batch files in one single script file.

Comment: `tclsh` seems to accept commands from its standard input also (according to [this site](http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tcl/tclsh.1.html) ). So things of the form `command | tclsh` should work. You'll just have to make the `command` write the correct tcl-commands to its standard output. `command` can be a simple batch script or even a call to a function that `echo`s those tcl commands. But as I am not used to tcl I don't know if it will work (is also the reason why I didn't put this as an answer). I'll let tcl-experts handle this

Comment: @J.Baoby, it's the batch experts we need. If this was unix shell, I'd recommend a here document, but I don't know how to do that in DOS batch.

Comment: @glennjackman unfortunately I don't think that exists in batch (I hope someone can prove me wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many things, there are pages on the Tcler's Wiki that can be looked to for interesting things. In particular, [this old page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2455) has some really useful techniques. As you read through, you'll see a history of techniques tried. They depend on the fact that Tcl commands can be prefixed with `::` usually (marking them as a weird label in the batch file language) and you can comment out blocks of code in Tcl with `if 0` (with Tcl not parsing the contents, beyond ensuring that it is brace-balanced, which code usually is).

The best technique is one that doesn't just make the code multilingual, but *also makes it easily readable.* Preserving readability is the key to not going crazy.

```
::if 0 {
@rem This code in here is pure batch script

echo off
set tclpath="C:\tclsh.exe"
%tclpath% "%~f0" %*

@rem Put this at the end; it means terminate since the “eof” label is end-of-file
@goto eof
}

# This code is the pure Tcl code

set a "this is the script"
puts $a
```

The other bits to be aware of:

- `"%~f0"` — This gets the *full path* to the “zero-th argument”, which is the name of the script you're running.
- `%*` — This is all the remaining arguments. It's a good idea to pass them on, and you can access them from Tcl using the list in the global `argv` variable.

Comment: I think it has to be `@goto :eof` (with colon) to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

> **I wonder whether I can include in the .bat file the commands of the .tcl script, so instead of having two files I just have one .bat file
>   that runs tclsh.exe and passes the commands to the tcl shell.**

### Easy peasy. . .

You can use a [CALL](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to a subroutine in a batch script that will append the commands to the dynamically created script file which you specify with the `set filepath` variable.

This way you have everything in the batch script and you do not need to worry about the tcl script file other than ensuring the `:tclshScript` routine that creates it has the correct syntax, etc.

You essentially build the tcl script logic with batch [`ECHO`](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) commands and it'll create it per run.

*Use **caution** with special characters though as the carat `^` symbol may be needed to [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) certain character to the tcl script if batch interprets those otherwise or you notice an issue.*

```
echo off
set tclpath="C:\tclsh.exe"
set filepath="C:\script.tcl"
IF EXIST "%filepath%" DEL /Q /F "%filepath%"
CALL :tclshScript
%tclpath% %filepath%
EXIT

:tclshScript
ECHO set a "this is the script">>%filepath%
ECHO puts $a>>%filepath%
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [CALL](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [ECHO](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [Escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: Just as a comment the `goto eof` didn't work at the beginning, so I changed it to `exit /b`, and then I realised I just needed to write `goto :eof`